# How to set a home page on a WordPress site?

Tags: site-url

URL returns this page: https://www.things-to-do-in-sebring-florida.com/

Link to home page returns this: https://www.things-to-do-in-sebring-florida.com/things-to-do-in-sebring-florida-2/

I recognize that somehow I've got the WP to recognize the "2" page as the home page, when it should use the page the URL returns.

Any suggested fixes? Thanks.

Willy

Comment: have you tried following the instructions on the [codex page on how to set a static home page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have a page/post that is titled 'things-to-do-in-sebring-florida' (without the dashes - space characters are automatically converted to dash/hyphen for the URL when WP saves the page/post).

At some point, you created a new page/post (or copied) with the same title. Since the title is the same, you can't have two URLs with the same name, so WP appends a '-2' for the copy.

Then, you assigned that '-2' page as the published page.

To fix, find the original (non dash-2) page/post, if it still exists. If you don't need it, delete it. If you do need it, edit the URL/link on the edit screen to something else.

Then bring up the current/live '-2' page, and change it's URL to remove the '-2'.

Comment: It's common around here to mark an answer correct. It helps the answerer, and others that might stumble on your question. Glad I can help.